# How to list files in git only upto n-levels?

Tags: git

I want to list the files currently tracked in a git repository.

So, I do `git ls-files`. However doing so, gives me the entire list including all the sub-directories, their sub-directories and so on..

I do not want this. Is there a way where I can specify the depth of the output of `ls-files` command?

Suppose I have a git repo:

```
mainrepo/
   sub-dir1
       subdir1.1
          subdir1.1.1
   sub-dir2
```

I only want to go to depth 1, perse. That means I only want ls-files to ouput

```
sub-dir1
sub-dir2
```

Comment: by _depth_ you mean pagination of results or depth of digging into the folders?

Comment: depth of digging into folders. I will update the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A somewhat rudimentary way is to strip each line up to (and including) an optional `/` character, and get the unique lines from that:

```
$ git ls-files | cut -f1 -d/ | uniq
```

(Note that I haven't been able to test this personally yet, because I'm on Windows using a limited Bash shell.)

Comment: Just saw your edit, working on revising to list the subdirectories, but not their contents.